# Windows_exporter: static list in left part "ignoring(state) (windows_service_state{...state="stopped"} == 0)" instead of dynamic output

Tags: prometheus

I have a `windows_exporter` query to monitor certain windows services.

```
(windows_service_state{app="xxx", name=~"tomcat.+|ot.+", state="running"} == 0) - ignoring(state) (windows_service_state{app="xxx", name=~"tomcat.+|ot.+", state="stopped"} == 0)
```

We have a lot of servers and I don't want to hardcode them, so I made the second part. In the second part are the services that need to be stopped. Unfortunately this is not possible, when you kill the service with Task Manager, it also goes into the stopped state.

```
ignoring(state) (windows_service_state{app="xxx", name=~"tomcat.+|ot.+", state="stopped"} == 0)
```

Now I have to do the second part of the query static (hardcoded), i.e. enter all servers where stopped is ok.

How-To to do this? Provide a list of servers and windows services where the stopped state is fine.

Here is the output from Prom Console

```
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerAdmin", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-adm1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerAdmin", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-adm1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcsadmin", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerFrontend", env="Int", instance="otcs-int-f1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-int", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerFrontend", env="Int", instance="otcs-int-f2.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-int", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerFrontend", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-f1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerFrontend", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-f2.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerFrontend", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-f3.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerFrontend", env="Test", instance="otcs-ooriom-f1.internal-21.example.org", job="yyy-servers-ooriom", name="otsystemcenteragent", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerIndex", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-idx1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerIndex", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-idx1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcsadmin", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerIndexAdmin", env="Int", instance="otcs-int-idxad1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-int", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerIndexAdmin", env="Int", instance="otcs-int-idxad1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-int", name="otcsadmin", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerIndexAdminSearch", env="Test", instance="otcs-ooriom-b1.internal-21.example.org", job="yyy-servers-ooriom", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerIndexAdminSearch", env="Test", instance="otcs-ooriom-b1.internal-21.example.org", job="yyy-servers-ooriom", name="otcsadmin", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerIndexAdminSearch", env="Test", instance="otcs-ooriom-b1.internal-21.example.org", job="yyy-servers-ooriom", name="otsystemcenteragent", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerSearch", env="Int", instance="otcs-int-src.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-int", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerSearch", env="Int", instance="otcs-int-src.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-int", name="otcsadmin", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerSearch", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-src1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerSearch", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-src1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcsadmin", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerSearch", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-src2.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcs", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="MercoServerSearch", env="Prod", instance="otcs-olap-src2.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="otcsadmin", state="stopped", webserver="IIS"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="DirectoryServices", env="Int", instance="otds-int-f1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-int", name="tomcat10", state="stopped"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="DirectoryServices", env="Prod", instance="otds-olap-f1.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="tomcat10", state="stopped"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="DirectoryServices", env="Prod", instance="otds-olap-f2.internal-08.example.org", job="yyy-servers-prod", name="tomcat10", state="stopped"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="DirectoryServices", env="Test", instance="otds-ooriom-f1.internal-21.example.org", job="yyy-servers-ooriom", name="tomcat10", state="stopped"}
0
windows_service_state{app="xxx", component="SystemCenter", env="Test", instance="otsc-ooriom-f1.internal-21.example.org", job="yyy-servers-ooriom", name="otsystemcentermanager", state="stopped"}
0
```

Comment: Explain what you are trying to accomplish with your query. You current (first) attempt right now returns all services that are neither running, nor stopped, but I somehow doubt that is what you want.

Comment: Correct. I wish to see if the service "failed" / have an issue. But there are services we stopped intentionally. I wish to exclude them from first (left) query in the second (right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of services, that are not in state `running` or `stopped` with the following query:

```
windows_service_state{app="xxx", name=~"tomcat.+|ot.+", state!~"running|stopped"} == 1
```

added bonus: label `state` will show actual state of the service.